# 71674705 value converted to 7.1674705E

Tags: java, excel

I have big problem with reading big numbers from excel in java. When i read 71674705 i get 7.1674705E which is not ok.

Example:

> double num =
>   cell.getNumericCellValue();

how can i prevent conversion between numbers that number will stay like 71674705.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number itself is not changing, only the representation when you convert it to a String. A `double` variable like you are using does not have an explicit format defined.

You can use `java.text.NumberFormat` ([javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)) to format the number any way you would like to see it.

Answer (score 3):

`num` is just a double, i.e. a binary floating-point number.  That formatting (exponential notation) is only an issue for printing.  So if you're just debugging, you shouldn't have to worry.  For production output, you can use a [`NumberFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) such as [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you are dealing with an integer and you want it as an integer value you can always try to do:
`Integer.valueOf(num)`

Edit: not valid for big numbers of course :-)